# STC Alcatel X080S Modem not working in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, usb-modem, alcatel

I am really blank, don't know what to do. I'm connecting the modem but it's not getting detected.

What is the way to get it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type

```
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get update
```

Then after upgrade, restart the system. Now it should work fine.